# the datasource does not support server side paging

Tags: asp.net, paging, objectdatasource

hi I have seen a couple of answers for this question but i have a peculiar case. I want to control what displays on an ASP.NET web form with Grid view control when user clicks on a drop down in the code behind. Like this:

```
If ddlProducts.SelectedValue <> "-1" Then
        gvCategories.DataSource = obj.getAll().Where(Function(c) c.productId = Integer.Parse(ddlProducts.SelectedValue)).Skip(0).Take(10)

        gvCategories.DataBind()
```

On using ObjectDatasource, I get an error-

```
Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'gvCategories'.  Remove one definition.
```

However, i need to do filtering of a list in code behind and can only set it to Datasource NOT DatasourceID. All of them emphasize no need for code behind. How do i go about it. Please pardon me if it has been answered but i failed to see it probably because i was in a hurry. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You CAN filter a list using the `ObjectDataSource`, you do it by adding a new `SelectParameter` to it and somehow (programatically for example) passing the value of the parameter. Then, the value is passed to your data provider class (the one the `ObjectDataSource` asks for the data) so you can use it in querying the data source.